# monotouch subviews horizontal paging

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, subview, scroll-paging

[image]

firstly, i want add 3 subviews with textview, image also edittext ;

view1 ; image,

view 2 : text, image,

view 3 : text, label

i want to scroll with async or with swipe

i used image scroll but can't find subviews

thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [UIScrollView](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/create_a_horizontal_scrolling_button_list/), or an [UIPageViewController](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/FrogScroller). Both will work, but the custom scroll view may be a bit simpler.